# AJAX Helper for NodeJS, instead of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I just want to do something like `$.get/post` on a server side script. Is there a better way instead of including the whole jQuery? I prefer not to use the messy get xml http requests stuff manually either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent to jquery.ajax in node.js is [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request)

It sits on top of the node core http and makes things nicer to work with. Allowing for both callback and streaming requests.

examples:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
  }
})

request.get('http://google.com/img.png').pipe(request.put('http://mysite.com/img.png'))
```

Answer (score 2):

require [http](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback). As found in their documentation you can make a request like the following:

```
var options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

There is a simple [GET](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) as well:

```
http.get("http://www.google.com/index.html", function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

You can also look into [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/) and [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request), there really are many options that you could use besides jquery.